# How to latest objects created in django models by similar field value?

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, django-queryset

I have created an app here people can upload 'csv' files of their items details to the server, and then perform various opertaions upon it. But, because every item has it's own unique ID, whenever a csv is uploaded, there is no way to figure out which item-batch was uploaded last.

### Upload function

This is my function in views.py importing the data in the Itembatch model:

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
class UploadedItems(ListView):
    model = ItemBatch
    ordering = ('name',)
    context_object_name = 'quizzes'
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/item_list.html'



    def get_queryset (self):
        # queryset = self.request.user.uploaded_by
        print("----------------" + str(ItemBatch.objects.latest('time')))
        return ItemBatch.objects.filter(uploaded_by=self.request.user)
```

And this is the model:

```
# item upload
class ItemBatch(models.Model):

    # uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_by')

    ttypes =(('Open','Open'),('Container','Container'),('Trailer','Trailer'),('All','All'))
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_by')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pid = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    length = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    volume = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    truck_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=0, choices=ttypes)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(max_length=100, blank=True,default=now)


    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

### What I tried

As you can see,

```
print("----------------" + str(ItemBatch.objects.latest('time')))
```

prints only the latest item and not the whole batch which I need. I need a queryset with all the items which were has the same time field and is the latest. Is there any way to do this without using any kind of BatchID in the model ?

This is my models database:

[image: 1]

As you can see, I want to segregate/differentiate between different batches of items.

Comment: so you need to take all elements with the same date, hour, minute and, maybe, second? (same as the latest 'time' element)

Comment: @LuSchink That is correct sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what i could understand from your question, you maybe need this (withouth testing it). Disable and enable USE_TZ if its True in settings.py.

```
latest_item = ItemBatch.objects.latest('time') 
from django.conf import settings
settings.USE_TZ = False 
latest_items = ItemBatch.objects.filter(time__date=latest_item.time.date(), time__hour=latest_item.time.hour, time__minute=latest_item.time.minute) 
settings.USE_TZ = True
```

'latest_items' contains all elements that match the date, hour and minute as the latest ItemBatch object. Add second too if you want it, but it may not work if there are lots of elements added in the same time.

Comment: When I ran your code I got this `Exception Value: 
expected string or bytes-like object
Exception Location: C:\Users\idadarklord\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py in parse_date, line 74`

Comment: You do realize the value stored in `latest_item` is the name of the last item, and not the latest time value which you are comparing in the next line.

Comment: Ensure you are passing the correct values of latest_item.time.date, hour, and minute to the query. Probably in some cases this need to be a datetime object or a string. Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#hour) for more info.

Comment: Thats not true. In latest_item you should have all the object.

Comment: As you can see in the model, `time = models.DateTimeField(max_length=100, blank=True,default=now)` I have passed correct date/time values in the time field. Do you see something wrong here ?  Btw when I run `latest_item = ItemBatch.objects.latest('time').time` I get this stored in the `active_item` = `2019-04-30 05:49:15.577822+00:00` .

Comment: I thought that too, maybe it is the whole object but when I just print the object as such `print(latest_item)` it just gives me 'B'.

Comment: That's because you defined __str__ method of the object. This is called when you pass the object to str() or print() functions.

Comment: You have a DateTime object on latest_item.time. Use it wisely on the other queryset and everything is gonna work. Make sure latest_item.time.hour, latest_item.time.date, latest_item.time.minute are correct values and these are the values expected by the queryset.

Comment: I understood your method, but cannot figure out why it returns me an error even with just  `latest_items = ItemBatch.objects.filter(time__date=latest_item.time.date)`

Comment: date must be called as a method: latest_item.time.date() .... already tested it now

Comment: Please, mark the answer as correct once you make it work. :)

Comment: Hey it worked! The date indeed needed the brackets and now there is no error, *BUT* now it returns no object whatsoever ? It is returning me an empty queryset. I will once I get it to work and I think we are 99.99% done.

Comment: So you checked there are items with the same date as the latest item you are getting?

Comment: When I just add the date() filter as such `latest_items = ItemBatch.objects.filter(time__date=latest_item.time.date(),uploaded_by=self.request.user)` it works and it gives me the correct list. But when I add just the hour part too `latest_items = ItemBatch.objects.filter(time__date=latest_item.time.date(), time__hour=latest_item.time.hour,uploaded_by=self.request.user)` it becomes empty :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192616/discussion-between-luschink-and-rohit-kumar).

Comment: I am sorry, but it using your code it still does not work unless I set my timezone to UTC.