# How to filter queryset against time in django with custom timezone?

Tags: python, django, timezone, utc

I know the question seems stupid, but for some reason I am not able to understand why my django app does not return the correct filtering results when I change my `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'` to 'TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata''. Everything else is working just fine, but when I change the timezone to my local timezone, it does not give any error, but the function in views.py also gives 0 matching results.

This question is also related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55915710/how-to-latest-objects-created-in-django-models-by-similar-field-value/55916053?noredirect=1#comment98487456_55916053).

This is my function in views.py importing the data in the Itembatch model:

```
@login_required
def upload_batch(request):
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/upload.html'
    prompt = {'order':'Order of csv should be first_name, last_name, email, ip_address, message'}
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request,template_name,prompt)

    csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)


    uploaded_by = request.user


    for column in csv.reader(io_string,delimiter=',',quotechar='|'):
        _, created = ItemBatch.objects.update_or_create(
            name = column[0],
            pid = column[1],
            quantity = column[2],
            length = column[3],
            width = column[4],
            height = column[5],
            volume = column[6],
            weight = column[7],
            truck_type = column[8],
            origin = column[9],
            destination = column[10],
            uploaded_by = uploaded_by
        )


    context = {}
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

This is my function in views.py to render the objects :

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
class UploadedItems(ListView):
    model = ItemBatch
    ordering = ('name',)
    context_object_name = 'quizzes'
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/item_list.html'



    def get_queryset (self):
        latest_item = ItemBatch.objects.latest('time') 
        return ItemBatch.objects.filter(time__date=latest_item.time.date(), 
time__hour=latest_item.time.hour, time__minute=latest_item.time.minute)
```

And this is the model:

```
# item upload
class ItemBatch(models.Model):

    # uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_by')

    ttypes =(('Open','Open'),('Container','Container'),('Trailer','Trailer'),('All','All'))
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_by')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pid = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    length = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    volume = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    truck_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=0, choices=ttypes)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(max_length=100, blank=True,default=now)


    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

This is my models database:

[image: 1]

### What I tried

A fellow SO user suggested I should try something like this, but it did not work either.

```
latest_item = ItemBatch.objects.latest('time') 
from django.conf import settings
settings.USE_TZ = False 
latest_items = ItemBatch.objects.filter(time__date=latest_item.time.date(), time__hour=latest_item.time.hour, time__minute=latest_item.time.minute) 
settings.USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: which queryset gives 0 results? and you say there's a function importing data into a model, but that's nowhere to be seen in the code you show.

Comment: what's `latest_item`? How can this code work if that isn't defined anywhere?

Comment: @dirkgroten Updated. The code `ItemBatch.objects.filter(time__date=latest_item.time.date(), time__hour=latest_item.time.hour, time__minute=latest_item.time.minute)`  returns an empty queryset unless I change my timezone to 'UTC' in settings.py

Comment: Are you on Django 2.2 and postgreSQL?

Comment: Django 2.0.1 and postgresql 9

Comment: try fetching `latest_item` also after switching off USE_TZ.

Comment: You can see in the 'What I tried' section I did switch the `settings.USE_TZ = False`. Please suggest something I have not yet tried.

Comment: But you’re fetching `latest_item` on the first line, before switching off. Read my comment and my answer before saying I’m telling stuff you’ve already tried. I’m not.

Comment: That said, moving the line `latest_item` won’t work either depending how the dates are saved in the db. My answer should provide the correct approach.

Comment: I did try it both ways, and yes it did not work like you already said. So yes, I did not specifically said I tried testing around, but I did try it in all possible ways and when all failed I am posting it on SO. Hence, I need to do something else other than what I have already tried.

Comment: I gave you the correct approach in my answer below using Trunc . Did you try that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `__date`, `__hour` and `__minute` are using the current timezone (whatever you defined as `settings.TIME_ZONE`). Whereas the python `datetime` object retrieved from the database with `latest` is always in UTC.

The thing to remember when being timezone aware is: All `datetime` objects passed around by Django are in UTC. The timezone is in general only used when displaying these datetimes in templates (rendering to the user) or receiving input values from forms (input from the user).

The exception here are the `Trunc` and `Extract` database functions, for which `__date`, `__hour` and `__minute` are shortcuts. They use the `settings.TIME_ZONE` unless you explicitly set `tzinfo` to `None` or `UTC`.

So you need to be in the same timezone context for both queries. The easiest is to do the whole thing at the database level:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, Subquery 

latest = ItemBatch.objects.order_by('-time').annotate(truncated_time=Trunc(
    'time', 'minute', output_field=DateTimeField())
qs = ItemBatch.objects.annotate(truncated_time=Trunc(
    'time', 'minute', output_field=DateTimeField()))\
        .filter(truncated_time=Subquery(latest.values('truncated_time')[:1]))
```

Note: Make sure your queryset doesn't include any rows where the field is `NULL` (not possible in your case, since `time` cannot be `NULL`), that will raise an exception when calling `Trunc` on it.

Comment: Do you have a trailing slash over here or is it intentional ? 
`'time', 'minute', output_field=DateTimeField()))\.filter(truncated_time=Subquery(latest.values('truncated_time')[:1]))`

Comment: The \ is the way you can have a line break in an expression in python. If you want to write the expression on one line of course remove the \